# I do not know how to pass this script through the CMD

Tags: cmd, line-continuation

I've instaled this script writen in python to delete tweets but i do not understand how to translate it so i can use it on windows

```
$ tweet-delete \
    --consumer_key=<consumer_key> \
    --consumer_secret=<consumer_secret> \
    --access_token_key=<access_token_key> \
    --access_token_secret=<access_token_secret> \
    --delete_older_than="7 days" \
    --delete_everything_after=2019-01-01
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The line continuation character for cmd.exe is a CARET `'^'`.

```
C:\> tweet-delete ^
    --consumer_key=<consumer_key> ^
    --consumer_secret=<consumer_secret> ^
    --access_token_key=<access_token_key> ^
    --access_token_secret=<access_token_secret> ^
    --delete_older_than="7 days" ^
    --delete_everything_after=2019-01-01
```

Also, cmd.exe does not recognize a shebang as the first line of a script. You will need to specify  `python tweet-delete.py ...` or have `.py` setup as an association to run python.exe.